# How can someone put the favorite question into his page here?

Tags: discussion

Many times, I wish, I had be able to keep, to collect and to manage my favorite questions and hints as their subjects here. But, I don't know how. I will be thankfull if I am informed of being such applictions at *StackExchange*

Comment: You can click the star to the left of a question to add it to your favorites list, and you can view your favorites using the tab on your user page: http://math.stackexchange.com/users/8581/babak-sorouh?tab=favorites.  Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

You can click the star to the left of a question to add it to your favorites list, and you can view your favorites using the tab on your user page:

https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8581/babak-sorouh?tab=favorites

Does that answer your question?